# JQuery UI Dialogs within a personalized class

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I have a div with the **class = "dialog-error"** applied to it. In jQuery I assign a dialog to this div like this: **$('.dialog-error').dialog({});**

I'd like to be able to target and modify only the ui classes that belong to my "dialog-error" class, so I tried:

```css
.dialog-error .ui-dialog-titlebar {
    background-color: red;
    background-image: none;
    color: white;
    font-size:small;
}
.dialog-error .ui-dialog-buttonpane { 
    font-size: 0.8em; 
}
```

But none apply. How can I target only the UI classes that belong to my class?

What I'm trying to achieve is to have at least two different categories (like: error dialogues and success dialogues) and switch back and forth just by changing the div's class.
Thanks much.

jquery code:

```
$('.dialog-error').dialog({
                resizable: false,
                height: 200,
                width: 350,
                modal: true,
                dialogClass: "dialog-error", //use this to affect the css 
                title: "Missing Information!",
                buttons: {
                    "Back": function() {
                        $(this).dialog("close");
                    }
                }

            });
```

HTML code:

```
<div class = "dialog-error" style = "display:none;"></div>
```

Added the **'dialogClass: "dialog-error"'** line as advised,but now the ui dialog won't show up at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I remember well jQuery UI first removes your div from the DOM, then it creates a new one and put the original in the content area. Your CSS class isn't applying because your div are *inside* the dialog, not *wrapping it*.

To accomplish your requirements, try to set the *dialogClass* option when initializing the modal.

See: http://api.jqueryui.com/dialog/#option-dialogClass

Comment: samuel, thanks for your answer ...can you give me an example?

Comment: @Nactus the example is in my fiddle in the comment

Comment: Edward, thanks for the demo, so the dialogClass: <<myClass>> has to be present to overwrite or -better to say- redirect the ui class to my own class, right?

Comment: Thanks Edward, that's exactly what I meant! Just an addition, you can switch styles whenever you want using the following call: $(".your-dialog-div").dialog("option", "dialogClass", ".new-dialog-class");

Comment: Thanks much Edward. Answer up-voted. I'm testing and I'll be back with a result.

Comment: Good. @Nactus to tag people in comment you must precede the name with @ or no tag will be set.

Comment: Alright @Edward, @samuelgrigolato, so this is my jquery code: `$('.dialog-error').dialog({
    resizable: false,
    height: 200,
    width: 350,
    modal: true,
    dialogClass: "dialog-error", //use this to affect the css 
    title: "Missing Information!",
    buttons: {
     "Back": function() {
      $(this).dialog("close");
     }
    }
    
   });` Just by adding the dialogClass: "dialog-error" line, the dialog does not show up anymore. If I comment it out my dialog is back. Is there a preferred place for this line?

Comment: is there a browser compatibility issue? I'm testing it on a linux Chrome.

Comment: Try to change the class name to dialogClass: "dialog-error-custom-style" (something like that, and don't forget to change in the CSS file as well), maybe you got some conflicting styles.

Comment: @samuelgrigolato I changed everything to dialog-error-custom-style same result. As soon as I comment-out the line with dialogClass everything works. Oh, and I tried the same script on Chrome, Opera and Firefox. All three do the same thing.

Comment: Everything? The $('.dialog-error') shouldn't be changed, just the dialogClass="dialog-error" attribute, and the CSS classes.

Comment: @samuelgrigolato, the html class attribute has to correspond to the css or the jquery in order to be able to be targeted, so I had to change all of them. Am I missing something? I guess my question is, does dialogClass' name has to correspond to the html's class or it has to be a new one? I'm a bit confused. Edward's example shows all the class-names having the same name. What Am I missing?

Comment: HTML class has to correspond to jQuery selector class. dialogClass value has to correspond to the CSS style block. If all the four are the same you can get some problems, because the DOM will look something like this:

<div class="dialog-error ui-dialog">
  <div class="dialog-error"> <!-- your div -->

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/35546/discussion-between-nactus-and-samuelgrigolato)